# Function in capture list: "extraneous argument label" error

Tags: swift, escaping, closures, swift5, capture-list

```
func customPrint(number: Int, via printingFunction: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    printingFunction(number)
}


class Temp {
    func tempPrintingFunction(number i: Int) {
        print(i)
    }

    func print5() {
        customPrint(number: 5) { [self] number in
            tempPrintingFunction(number: number)
        }
    }
}

Temp().print5()
```

This code is fine: compiles and works as expected.
But when I pass function itself in capture list instead of `self`:

```
func print5() {
    customPrint(number: 5) { [tempPrintingFunction] number in
        tempPrintingFunction(number: number)
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Extraneous argument label 'number:' in call

When I remove the label, everything backs to normal.
But it's weird. What is it? Bug or feature? I can't find any information about this neither in documentation nor on forums.

Bonus question:
Why doesn't the code crash, when I pass `unowned self` to the capture list? Shouldn't it crash? I want it to crash

Edited:
By the way, is there any difference in this situation between capturing `self` and function itself? In terms of retain cycles, etc. If we capture function, `self` will be captured as well, isn't it?

Comment: `unowned self` would only crash if `self` has been released. From the sample you've shared, it doesn't appear that `self` has been released at the time the closure is executed.

Comment: @Anwuna How should I change the code, to release "self" by the time the closure is executed?

Comment: If you're using a playground project, you won't observe the crash, the only thing that would happen is the method on self won't get executed. Instead, test it on an actual iOS/Mac app. The easist way to test is to use ViewControllers. Let me know if you want me to share a sample.

Comment: @Anwuna That's interesting, I didn't know this nuance of Playground before. Ok, then how to make "the method on self won't get executed"? I think that would be enough "crashy" 

Comment: Wrap the body of `customPrint` function in `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1)` to cause a slight delay.  Also, initialize the `Temp` class like `var temp: Temp! = Temp(); temp.print5(); temp = nil`